# Unity3d C# respawning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

If I test my game in Unity and I respawn I get my 3 lifes back.
But when I build the game, and I respawn I only get 2 lifes back.

Here is my code (not the full code) that I used for the respawning:

```
public int StarterLives; // 3
public GameObject plr; // My Player
public float maxVoidDist; // -10
public Object respawnLevel; // Level01 (My first and only asset)
public Text LivesHolder; // The text object (UI)

private Vector3 respawnPoint; // This gets updated in Start() and becomes the first position of the player
private string deadLevel; // This gets updated in Start() and becomes the name of my respawnlevel
private int lives; // This gets updated in Start() and becomes StarterLives (3)
private bool delay1 = false;


void Update () {
    if ((plr.transform.position.y <= maxVoidDist) && (delay1.Equals(false)))
    {
        delay1 = true;
        if((lives - 1) <= 0)
        {
            Application.LoadLevel(deadLevel);
            lives = StarterLives + 1;
        } else
        {
            plr.transform.position = respawnPoint;
        }

        lives = lives - 1;
        updateLives();
        delay1 = false;
    }
}

void updateLives()
{
    LivesHolder.text = "Lives: " + lives;
}
```

Full code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    public int StarterLives;
    public GameObject plr;
    public float maxVoidDist;
    public Object respawnLevel;
    public Text LivesHolder;

    private Vector3 respawnPoint;
    private string deadLevel;
    private int lives;
    private bool delay1 = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 1;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        respawnPoint = plr.transform.position;
        deadLevel = respawnLevel.name;
        lives = StarterLives;
        updateLives();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if ((plr.transform.position.y <= maxVoidDist) && (delay1.Equals(false)))
        {
            delay1 = true;
            if((lives - 1) <= 0)
            {
                Application.LoadLevel(deadLevel);
                lives = StarterLives + 1;
            } else
            {
                plr.transform.position = respawnPoint;
            }

            lives = lives - 1;
            updateLives();
            delay1 = false;
        }
    }

    void updateLives()
    {
        LivesHolder.text = "Lives: " + lives;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why u have such thing as lives = lives - 1; in ur Update function. (if anything, I'd change it to lives -= 1;)

Comment: For me it is easier to use lives = lives - 1, because I am used to do doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I see some strange things, in your code, I hope they can represent the issue:

1)

```
if((lives - 1) <= 0)
```

With this test, if you have 1 life remaining, you would restart the level. Is it what you want?

2)

```
Application.LoadLevel(deadLevel);
lives = StarterLives + 1;
```

In this snippet, the second line is useless because, as soon as you invoke `LoadLevel()`, the new scene is loaded and the rest of your code is not executed. So, `lives = StarterLives + 1;` is dead code.

3) Regarding the second point, let's suppose that the order of those lines is inverted (so, they are in the "right" order). It seems that you're trying to update some values in order to have them as the level restarts. But I can't see a [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) in your code, so values' preservation is useless.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1)
It only goes off when you should lose a life like when you fall down below Y - 10.
Meaning that you can put it at the top wich I did first, but then I tried to solve the problem by placing it all the way down.
To try and prevent -1 life to run multiple times.

2)
I tried that but it seemed like the code kept running, ill try and do what you say.

3)
Ill try that thank you.

Comment: @Bram: OK, I understood! I Hope that my hints would be useful, good luck ;)

Comment: Alright, on your second point I tried to put a debug.Log(); right after: lives = StarterLives + 1, and it printed it out in the console meaning that the code kept running

Comment: On your third point I tried to put an object into the game while it was running, and it seemed to dissapear after it loaded the level ill put the code in the correct order and see how it goes

Comment: @Bram: "Alright, on your second point I tried to put a debug.Log(); [...]" This is very strange, and contrary to the typical behaviour. I think that the new scene is not immediately started, and the remaining code continues to be executed until its complete loading. This could be, in fact, the reason of your discrepancies among editor- and build- versions.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help so far.

Is there any function that starts when the level is fully loaded?
If so I can try putting lives = StarterLives; in there.

I tried to put it in Awake(), didn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: So I have been thinking and I think I found the issue.
Right before changing the level 1 last Update occurs right before the level gets loaded.

Because of that it executes lives = lives - 1 right after the level gets loaded.
Ill try and solve the issue based on this theory.

Comment: So, I fixed that problem, now once my level I have 0 lifes but when I reload the level I have 3 lifes. Meaning that StarterLives probably wasn't loaded once I started the game.